# Display stored value in Meta Box

Tags: metabox

How to display stored value in Meta Box ?

I added Meta Box with below code.

```
add_meta_box('wp_news_settings', 'News Settings', 'news_settings_html', 'news', 'normal', 'default');
```

My call back function is like below

```
public function news_settings_html($post)
    {
        $wpwi_stored_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
        
       
        $fields = [
            'location' => '<input type="text" value="'. (!empty($wpwi_stored_meta) && $wpwi_stored_meta['location']) ? $wpwi_stored_meta['location'][0] : ''.'"  name="location" />',  
        ];
            wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'wpwi_nonce');
            
        ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <?php
                    foreach($fields as $key=> $field) {
                        ?>
                            <tr valign="top">
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <label for="location">
                                        <?= _e(ucfirst($key), 'textdomain');?>
                                    </label>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <?= $field; ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
        <?php
    }
```

But I am not getting Stored Meta Box Value.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

you have to pass get_post_meta() field name in your input type name which you have to store user data value and if it's not created then it will create in save_your_fields_metabox() function.

```
public function news_settings_html($post){

global $post;
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_store_field_name', true);

<input type="hidden" name="your_meta_box_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)); ?>">

<input type="text" value="<?php
        if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['text-address'])) {
            echo $meta['text-address'];
        }
        ?>" name="your_store_field_name[text-address]" />
}
```

you have to store your textbox value in database,then you can get them on front page.

```
function save_your_fields_metabox($post_id) {

    // verify nonce
    if (isset($_POST['your_meta_box_nonce']) && !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['your_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

   // check permissions
    if (isset($_POST['post_type'])) { 
        if ('careers' === $_POST['post_type']) {
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
                return $post_id;
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        }
    }

    // if field is not created early then it will create here!
    $old = get_post_meta($post_id, 'your_store_field_name', true);
        if (isset($_POST['your_store_field_name'])) { 
            $new = $_POST['your_store_field_name'];
            if ($new && $new !== $old) {
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'your_store_field_name', $new);
            } elseif ('' === $new && $old) {
                delete_post_meta($post_id, 'your_store_field_name', $old);
            }
        }
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_your_fields_metabox');
```

and on front page, suppose it's **page.php** , just you have to get meta field name and get with it's input text name.

```
 $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_store_field_name', true);
    <h1>Text Input</h1>
    <?php echo $meta['text-address']; ?>
```

2. 

Please try to get data from post meta, if it's really stored or not.
you can refer this, in detail  [Metabox](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/)

```
<?php
    $args = array('post_type' => 'news');
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->next_post();
    $id= $the_query->post->ID;
    $location = get_post_meta($id, 'your_store_field_name', true);
    echo $location;
    endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Akshail Tejani. Actually I would like to pass value through Array and I would like to get output using Loop. Could you please help me in this way ? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, Sure @Foysal

Comment: I added 2nd point , please try that @Foysal